# spark Local mode vs standalone cluster in term of cores and threads usage

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, local, apache-spark-standalone

im comparing between pyspark `local mode` and `standalone mode` where

**local** :

```
findspark.init('C:\spark\spark-3.0.3-bin-hadoop2.7')
conf=SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("local[*]")
conf.setAppName('firstapp')

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)
```

**standalone** :

```
findspark.init('C:\spark\spark-3.0.3-bin-hadoop2.7')
conf=SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("spark://127.0.0.2:7077")
conf.setAppName('firstapp')

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)
```

plus starting the Master and the workers using :

**Master**
`bin\spark-class2.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master`

**Worker** multiple times depending on the number of workers
`bin\spark-class2.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker -c 1 -m 1G spark://127.0.0.1:7077` where '1' mean one core and '1G' mean 1gb or Ram.

**my question is** :  what is the difference between **local mode** and **standalone mode** in term of the usage of threads and cores ?